# Simplifying conditional statements for transaction code

Tags: c#

I have below code in one function:

```
public void func()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerpay) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(warrantypay) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(maintanceplan))
    {
        if (customerpay == "Include" && warrantypay == "Include" && maintanceplan == "Include")
        {
            transactiontype = "," + "[Population].[Transaction Type Code].&[C^W^I]";
        }
        else if (customerpay == "Include" && warrantypay == "Include" && maintanceplan != "Include")
        {
            transactiontype = "," + "[Population].[Transaction Type Code].&[C^W]";
        }
        else if (customerpay == "Include" && warrantypay != "Include" && maintanceplan != "Include")
        {
            transactiontype = "," + "[Population].[Transaction Type Code].&[C]";
        }
        else if (customerpay != "Include" && warrantypay == "Include" && maintanceplan == "Include")
        {
            transactiontype = "," + "[Population].[Transaction Type Code].&[W^I]";
        }
        else if (customerpay != "Include" && warrantypay != "Include" && maintanceplan == "Include")
        {
            transactiontype = "," + "[Population].[Transaction Type Code].&[I]";
        }
        else if (customerpay != "Include" && warrantypay == "Include" && maintanceplan != "Include")
        {
            transactiontype = "," + "[Population].[Transaction Type Code].&[W]";
        }
        else if (customerpay == "Include" && warrantypay != "Include" && maintanceplan == "Include")
        {
            transactiontype = "," + "[Population].[Transaction Type Code].&[C^I]";
        }
    }
}
```

I need to simplify the above `if`-`else` C# code. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: One thing you could do is have those `(stringVar) == "Include"` as boolean checks at the start of the if statement, like so: `if(/*none are null*/) { bool hasCustomerPay = customerpay == "Include"; bool hasWarrentPay = warrentpay == "Include"; bool hasMaintancePlan = maintanceplan == "Include"; /*long if-else here*/ }`

Comment: What is logic behind this code? A bet you have some rules to decide whether you add one or more 'lines' to transactiontype, and rule which you use for generation C^WI combinations

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
public void func()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerpay) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(warrantypay) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(maintanceplan))
        return;

    if (customerpay != "Include" && warrantypay != "Include" && maintanceplan != "Include")
        return;

    List<char> parts = new List<char>();
    if (customerpay == "Include")
        parts.Add("C");
    if (warrantypay == "Include")
        parts.Add("W");
    if (maintanceplan == "Include")
        parts.Add("I");

    transactiontype = ",[Population].[Transaction Type Code].&[" + string.Join("^", parts) + "]";
}
```

First, we simply return if any of the strings is empty; by inverting the logic, we can reduce one indentation level that makes the code unecessarily complicated. We also return for the single case that isn’t handled in your original code: If all three strings are not `"Include"`.

After that, it’s easy once you find out the pattern of your string. The only changing part of your result string is in the brackets at the end. There are three possible characters: `C`, `W`, and `I`. They appear if the corresponding string equals to `"Include"`. The characters are separated by a `^`. So we just check each condition alone, and collect the characters in a list. Then we join with the separation character and build the final result string.

Comment: +1 beat me to it :)  Though, you could probably omit the IsNullOrEmpty checks since the inequality check takes care of it.

Comment: +1 for beating me to it also :) ... *and* for handling the unlikely case where none of the strings say "Include".

Comment: @DanLyons Good idea, but that is actually only half-true. When just one of the strings equals `"Include"`, then the inequality check is skipped, but the two other variables could still be null ;)

Comment: @poke thanks for your solution.i have modified question by added some more conditions. could you please check once again and please let me know how can i use this solution for that

Comment: @SivaRajini Does the order of the resulting things matter?

Comment: @SivaRajini do not modify question in the way which invalidates answers. If these answers cannot help in your real problem, then ask another question

Answer (score 10):

Well the first condition could be reversed, immediately reducing the nesting level:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerpay) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(warrantypay) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(maintanceplan))
{
   return;
}

// rest of conditions
```

This code *looks* like sample code, but I'll say it anyway: `func` is a bad name for any function, especially one that returns `void`. And to follow naming C# conventions it should be named `Func` - but that clashes with the framework's `Func<T>`, making it even more confusing. Give meaningful names!!

Back to the `else if` blocks..

This code builds a `string`. I think `transactionType` should be `transactionTypeBuilder` and be of type `StringBuilder` - don't concatenate strings like that; **build** them instead!

Moreover, each branch is really coming up with *the very last part* to be added to the string, so it would be easier to understand what the code does at a glance if you introduced a variable and changed the `transactionType` assignment to this:

```
transactionType = string.Format(",[Population].[Transaction Type Code].&[{0}]", code);
```

Where `code` is what each branch is trying to solve. This leaves you with this:

```
var code = string.Empty;
if (customerpay == "Include" && warrantypay == "Include" && maintanceplan == "Include")
{
    code = "C^W^I";
}
else if (customerpay == "Include" && warrantypay == "Include" && maintanceplan != "Include")
{
    code = "C^W";
}
else if (customerpay == "Include" && warrantypay != "Include" && maintanceplan != "Include")
{
    code = "C";
}
else if (customerpay != "Include" && warrantypay == "Include" && maintanceplan == "Include")
{
    code = "W^I";
}
else if (customerpay != "Include" && warrantypay != "Include" && maintanceplan == "Include")
{
    code = "I";
}
else if (customerpay != "Include" && warrantypay == "Include" && maintanceplan != "Include")
{
    code = W";
}
else if (customerpay == "Include" && warrantypay != "Include" && maintanceplan == "Include")
{
    code = "C^I";
}
```

Now each test seems to be crying for a `bool`. Consider this:

```
var code = string.Empty;
var includeCustomerPay = (customerPay == "Include");
var includeWarrantyPay = (warrantyPay == "Include");
var includeMaintenancePlan = (maintenancePlan == "Include");

if (includeCustomerPay && includeWarrantyPay && includeMaintancePlan)
{
    code = "C^W^I";
}
else if (includeCustomerPay && includeWarrantyPay && !includeMaintancePlan
{
    code = "C^W";
}
else if (includeCustomerPay && !includeWarrantyPay && !includeMaintancePlan)
{
    code = "C";
}
else if (!includeCustomerPay && includeWarrantyPay && includeMaintancePlan)
{
    code = "W^I";
}
else if (!includeCustomerPay && !includeWarrantyPay && includeMaintancePlan)
{
    code = "I";
}
else if (!includeCustomerPay && includeWarrantyPay && !includeMaintancePlan)
{
    code = "W";
}
else if (includeCustomerPay && !includeWarrantyPay && includeMaintancePlan)
{
    code = "C^I";
}
```

Isn't something starting to emerge? The "code" for each `bool` is always in the same order, and separated by a `"^"`.

Therefore, the whole condition can be dropped, with the help of a bit of [linq](/questions/tagged/linq):

```
var codes = new[] 
              { 
                  includeCustomerPay ? "C" : string.Empty,
                  includeWarrantyPay ? "W" : string.Empty,
                  includeMaintenancePlan ? "I" : string.Empty
              };

var code = string.Join("^", codes.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty));
transactionType = string.Format(",[Population].[Transaction Type Code].&[{0}]", code);
```

Comment: thanks for your solution.i have modified question by added some more conditions. could you please check once again and please let me know how can i use this solution for that updated question

Comment: @SivaRajini you realize you've just invalidated both answers with that edit? I suggest you rollback that edit, rework your code per our answers (and accept either), and post another CR question with your updated code. More work, but more votes for everyone :)

Comment: Agreed; just starting a new answer with the full code would be fine too (i.e. without reworking it), as the situation changed quite a bit, and our solutions don’t really apply easily to the new thing.